# Install a new module to drupal website localhost

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, drupal-8

Am new to drupal, am working on version 8.3.5 trying to install a new module administration menu to my localhost without FTP.

I have extracted all files of module to /sites/all/modules folder.The menu is displaying in 'Extend' section but not displaying in my website.

The modules are 'checked' too, but how to enable it and display in my website? Thanks

I have executed this command `sudo chown -R www-data sites/all/modules`
 too.

1. Current output:-(Only one admin toolbar already there after installation of drupal)

[image]

2. Current Settings in Extend section: (Admin toolbar always checked and unable to uncheck too.How to activate and deactivate this module here?)
3. Expected Output is two admin toolbar like this:- (Below screenshot is an example of administration menu module in drupal7)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Steps to install new modules**

1. Download and extract the module to to the modules folder.Since it is a contibute module better add it in a  folder named contrib. So the path will  be `drupal_folder/modules/contrib/your_module`
2. Now your_module will be available in the List section on `http://your_site.com/admin/modules`
3. Check ane enable your_module
4. Now the enabled module will be checked in the `List section` and also available in the Uninstall section(`http://your_site.com/admin/modules/uninstall`)
5. Clear cache

**Using drush**

1. Download and install modules with drush from terminal

   `drush dl module_name
   drush en module_name`
2. Try to clear caches using drush from the terminal.

   `drush cr`

**Update drush**

Note: Drupal8 requires latest version of drush
To find current version of Drush use the command:

`drush --version`

If its alower version please update drush using composer, if composer already installed skip the step to install composer.

```
cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
source ~/.bashrc
composer global require drush/drush:8.*
drush --version
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have done all the settings but am geting an error while using drush:-



PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydrupal/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 65
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in
/opt/lampp/htdocs/mydrupal/core/includes/bootstrap.inc, line 65

Comment: Please use the latest version of drush7/8 for drupal8.Also refer thiss one https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155084/running-drush-returns-an-error

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8, the correct location for modules is the *modules/* folder which is at the root of your project. People also add a *contrib/* and *custom/* folder inside *modules/* to differentiate the ones you create from the ones you install.

I'm curious about how the module has been discovered being at the location you indicated. Anyway, you say that the administration menu module is checked so it should be installed. Do you have a toolbar at the top of your website pages? What is the name of the module that is checked in Extend?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, the module ie checked is Admin Toolbar.I have only one toolbar at my home page which was already there by default. I have updated my question, please check the attached screenshots.Thank you.

Comment: @Maaaatt you can also add your contributed or custom module in sites/all/modules directory.

Comment: @vishwa. That is Drupal 7 which you are talking about. In drupal 8  is directly under /modules folder.

Comment: @Rony Samuel i am talking about D8 only. Please can you try adding a module in sites/all/modules and check in admin panel. I Have done it multiple times in drupal 8. The only thing is you need to create the all and modules directory under sites as sites/all/modules.

Comment: Durpal.org do suggest adding them in modules/ folder in root directory. But it will still work the same even if you add in the sites/all/modules directory. @Maaatt suggestion is incorrect as how the module is discovered when added under sites/all/modules.

Comment: @vishwa indeed I tried and you're right. I would say it's still working for backward compatibility but it's probably good (better?) practice to put your modules in the modules/ folder for drupal 8 and probably future drupal versions.

Comment: @maaaatt and you are right, it must be for backward compatibility.